# Able to login using Old password in LDAP

Tags: java, windows, authentication, ldap

We are using LDAP for windows authentication in our application.

The code looks like

```
public LdapContext adAuth(String userName, String passWord, String domainName, String url,String port) {
    LdapContext ctx = null;
    try{
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://"+url+":"+port);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName + "@" + domainName );
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, passWord);
        ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
    }catch(NamingException nex){
        ctx = null;
    }
    return ctx;
}
```

This is working fine. But the issue is when a user changes his password and setup a new password he is able to login using the new password and ***OLD*** password. How do i prevent this? User should be able to login using the new password only.

Comment: What Windows version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically it happens due to [default timeout of 60 min](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/906305) for old passwords or  due to replication. See more [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/3878d29d-dbdf-4e6d-ac26-00bb4b216159/active-directory-users-can-access-with-the-old-password-?forum=winserverDS).